# Querying Json Documents in Raven DB - passing to MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, ravendb

Below is a Json Document in Raven DB. How can I write a query that gets all movies playing in this theater and pass it on as a model to a view in MVC? Thanks for your help.

```
 {
  "TheaterId": "Hd45",
  "TheaterName" : "Blvd",

  {
     "MovieName": "Wild wild west",
     "ReleaseDate": "12th Dec",
     "NumOfShows ": "5"    
  }
  {
     "MovieName": "Shrek",
     "ReleaseDate": "12th Dec",
     "NumOfShows ": "5"    
   }
   {
     "MovieName": "Ronin",
     "ReleaseDate": "12th Dec",
     "NumOfShows ": "5"    
   }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [NoSQL with RavenDB and ASP.NET MVC - Part 1](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/05/26/nosql-with-ravendb-and-asp-net-mvc-part-1.aspx) Hope this helps, Matt

Answer (score 1):

The actual query should be quite simple...
Assuming you have a model like this:

```
public class Theater
{
    public string TheaterId { get; set; }
    public string TheaterName { get; set; }

    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

    public class Movie
    {
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public int NumOfShows { get; set; }
    }
}
```

... then the raven query could look like that:

```
    private ActionResult MoviesForTheater(string theaterId)
    {
        var theater = Session.Load<Theater>(theaterId);
        if (theater == null)
            return HttpNotFound("Theater not found!");

        var movies = theater.Movies.Select(movie => movie.MovieName).ToList();
        return View(movies);
    }
```

BUT - I'm wondering why you have your id-property named "TheaterId" instead of "Id", which is the default RavenDB-convention.

Probably you want to look at [RacconBlog](https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog) for a really good example of a well designed MVC-app with RavenDB.